# How to set cloud-init/no-cloud in Ubuntu 22.04 to stop automatically rebooting

Tags: 22.04, cloud-init

I want to stop Ubuntu install after finishing to reboot. In `user-data` I tried to use:

```
power_state:
    delay: 30
    mode: reboot
    message: Rebooting machine
    condition: false
```

but is not working.

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the server installer from rebooting after performing an autoinstall?

Comment: @AndrewLowther yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `user-data` snippet that can be used to prevent the reboot after an autoinstall is finished.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  shutdown: reboot
runcmd:
  - |
    mv /sbin/reboot /sbin/reboot.real
    install -m 0755 -o root -g root /dev/null /sbin/reboot
    cat <<EOF > /sbin/reboot
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    exit 0
    EOF
```

**how it works**

The autoinstall configuration does **not** provide a way to pause when finished.  The autoinstall configuration has a `shutdown` setting, but [the only allowed options](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/428dc9502f8d569700e2f4ff71c618d027465c34/subiquity/server/controllers/shutdown.py#L43) are `reboot` or `poweroff`.  When the autoinstall finishes, the installer (*subiquity*) [will run](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/428dc9502f8d569700e2f4ff71c618d027465c34/subiquity/server/controllers/shutdown.py#L126) either `/sbin/reboot` or `/sbin/poweroff` based on the setting.  Moving the `/sbin/reboot` executable will prevent the reboot.  A script is put it its place to prevent an error.

When the installation finishes the console will simply pause with the last line

```
finish: subiquity/Shutdown/shutdown: mode=REBOOT
```

A reboot can be performed manually using `/sbin/reboot.real` (or another mechanism like pressing the keyboard sequence `ctrl-alt-del`).

**notes**

- I tested using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`)